# rspec vs 'url_validation' gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, rspec2

I'm struggling with rspec as a new Rails person and I have a need to validate a url passed into Active Record. This is probably due to my ignorance so pls point me in the right direction. The video_url is a string field which I'd like to validate as being a valid URL. Looking around, I chose this gem because it appeared to be fully tested in rspec. For my test I didn't see how I could incorporate his validation test into my model test.

In rails console, I created a Post object and ensured that if I put a bogus URL that I knew would not be found, I would get an error. The curious thing is that attempting to replicate this in a test with the gem installed fails the test because it finds no errors. I expected an error of some kind as I got in console. My question is what am I doing wrong in that it gets no errors? I've made several attempts to triangulate what might be causing it but the gem doesn't seem to work in rspec? I would have thought that if I could get it to work in console, I can get it to work in rspec?

post.rb

```
 class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :body, :title, :image, :video_title, :video_url
   validates_presence_of :title, :body, :author
   validates :video_url, :presence => true, :if => :video_title_present?, :url => { 
        :check_path => [ 300..399, 400..499, 500..599 ], :allow_nil => true,
        :url_not_accessible_message => "must be valid.",
        :invalid_url_message => "must be valid.",
        :url_invalid_response_message => "must be valid."}

   def video_title_present?
     !self.video_title.blank?
   end
   belongs_to :author, class_name: "User"
 end
```

post_spec.rb

```
 before do
   @post = Post.new(title: "foo", body: "my body here")
 end

 describe "validates with video links" do
   it "validates with video url and video title" do
     @post.video_url = "http://heckitoqi.com"
     @post.video_title = "my title"
     @post.should have_at_least(1).error_on(:video_url)
   end
 end
```

Output in console:

```
 Failure/Error: @post.should have_at_least(1).error_on(:video_url)
 expected at least 1 error on :video_url, got 0
```

In some of my errors, I attempted a more open-ended error, but it fails by not catching any errors.

Here is a short version of my smoke test of the model using Rails console:

```
 u = User.first
 p = Post.new(title: "title", body: "body", video_title: "vtitle", video_url: "http://heckitoqi.com")
 p.author = u
 p.save!

 >> HTTPI GET request to heckitoqi.com (net_http)
 >> ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Video url must be valid.
```

If I can get it to validate in the console, then my implementation of the test is at fault, right? I just don't see what I'm doing wrong. thanx, sam

Comment: Did part of your spec code get chopped out of your paste? I'm not seeing a line that reads `@post.should have_at_least(1).error_on(:video_url)` in your paste above.

Comment: Yes, that's a critical thing to forget! thx!

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the gem, but I notice you're passing a lot of options to it along with the validation. Perhaps remove the options one at a time and see if it becomes more reliable in both environments?

Comment: Also, your test URL value in your spec above is different than your test URL value in your `rails console` example. Make sure that you're playing around with the same values in both environments.

Comment: Yes, I have validated that the test params match and that the results are the same. I have yanked the options in different combos to the same result. One curious thing about this gem is that I think it uses the translation capabilities to report errors. To wit: 'Validation failed: Video url translation missing: en.activerecord.errors.models.post.attributes.video_url.url_not_accessible'